# Prove $g: C[0,1] \to \mathbb{R} = f \mapsto \int_0^1fk$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, proof-writing

Let $C[0,1]$ be the metric space of continuous functions on $[0,1]$ with metric $d(f,g) = \sup \{|f(x) - g(x)|:x \in [0,1]\}$.

Let $g: C[0,1] \to \mathbb{R} = f \mapsto \int_0^1fk$, where $k$ is a given function in $C[0,1]$.

Prove $g$ is continuous.

**Proof:**

$$
\begin{align*}
|g(f) - g(f')| &= \left \lvert \int_0^1fk - \int_0^1f'k \right \rvert \\
&\leq \int_0^1|fk - f'k| \\
&= \int_0^1|k||f - f'| \\
&\leq \int_0^1|k| \cdot \int_0^1|f - f'| \\
&\leq \int_0^1|k| \cdot d(f,f'). \\
\end{align*}
$$

Thus, for sufficiently close $f$ and $f'$, $g(f)$ and $g(f')$ are arbitrarily close.  QED.

1. Is the proof correct?
2. If this a good approach? Is there a simpler one?
3. Please evaluate (or improve) the exposition.

---

*After comments from @Feng and @OliverDiaz:*

I think my misunderstanding comes from failing to realize: A sequence of continuous functions $\{f_n\}$ can have constant integral but still unbounded $f_n(c)$.  [I'm thinking of a sequence of continuous functions converging to Dirac delta, though I don't know a name for such.  Is there a classic example?]

Thus, $k(c)$ can be arbitrarily large even if $\int|k|$ is arbitrarily small! So, as Feng and Oliver Diaz write, I need to take $k$'s max and use that.

Is my intuition correct?  And, **can you provide a reference or clearer explanation showing why** $\int |f||g|$ is not in general $\leq \int|f| \cdot \int |g|$.

Revised, the proof ends:

**Proof:**

$$
\begin{align*}
&= \int_0^1|k||f - f'| \\
&\leq \max|k| \cdot \int_0^1|f - f'| \\
&\leq \max|k| \cdot d(f,f'). \\
\end{align*}
$$

with $k$ having a max on $[0,1]$ by the Extreme Value Theorem.

Comment: $\int_0^1|k||f - f'|\leq \int_0^1|k| \cdot \int_0^1|f - f'|$ is not necessarily true. It should be something like $\int_0^1 |f||g|\leq \text{max }|f|\cdot \int_0^1|g|$.

Comment: @Feng So that I can understand, can you please provide a simple counter example, or help me understand intuitively why it's not generally true?

Comment: You should  fist bound $k$ by some contest and then pull it out of the integral

Comment: Regarding your question about the inequality of integrals and products: take f=g=x. Then integral of fg=x^2 is x^3/3 while the other side of inequality you are asking about is (x^2/2)(x^2/2). But 1/3 <=1/4 is false

Comment: Also see Cauchy-schwartz inequality for a statement that is true - basically just square the integral of fg and then it's less than product of the two integrals